# Soring and counting records

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with people with multiple entry and exit times during the day. This is done when they enter or exit certain location. How do I sort out records only to capture the last record. The Entry records. I am trying to sort out the persons still inside the location.

- Name    - Action -   DateTime
- John    - Entry  -   29-10-2019/09:00
- John    - Exit   -   29-10-2019/10:00
- John    - Entry  -   29-10-2019/11:00
- Eva     - Entry  -   29-10-2019/09:00

Now how do I count only the people who entered and are still inside, not the one that exited the location. In the case above.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Can we assume 1) Name is unique and 2) Any entry w/o an exist is assumed still in the building (Say they exist with someone else for lunch and don't badge out;we'd have two entries but no exists..)

Comment: Dear Zohar, thank you for your comment. Will try to follow the instruction.

Comment: xObert,  we have nameID which we use as identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
 name
 ,Action
 ,DateTime
from
(
select
 name
 ,Action
 ,DateTime
,row_number() over (partition by name order by DateTime desc) rn
from <table>
) a
where rn=1
```

This catches the latest entry for each name.

If you want to see the ones still inside, just add

```
and Action='Entry'
```

Comment: Dear Soren, thanks a lot, it is exactly what I needed.